# Training loss won't increase or decrease at all

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm new to PyTorch and CNN implementation and I'm trying to train a simple CNN on the Fashion-MNIST dataset using PyTorch. I've done it before using a simple MLP and I got an accuracy of over 90% and a loss visibly decreasing each epoch, but with this CNN model I get just utter trash during inference.

```py
model1 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=2, padding=2),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = (2,2)),
    nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=2, padding=2),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2)),
    nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=2, padding=2),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(256, 64),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(64, 32),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(32, 10),
    F.softmax(dim=1)
)
```

The training loop is something like this:

```py
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    run_loss=0
    for image, label in trainloader:
        optimz.zero_grad()
        loss = criterion(model1(image), label)
        loss.backward()
        optimz.step()
        run_loss += loss.item() 
    else:
        print("epoch {} loss = {}".format(epoch, run_loss/len(trainloader)))
```

and these are the results during training:

```
epoch 0 loss = 2.302614325907693
epoch 1 loss = 2.302605228891759
epoch 2 loss = 2.302595841605018
epoch 3 loss = 2.3025884717258056
epoch 4 loss = 2.302580612046378
epoch 5 loss = 2.3025743503814566
epoch 6 loss = 2.3025668882357793
epoch 7 loss = 2.302558557056923
epoch 8 loss = 2.3025530574164157
epoch 9 loss = 2.3025459475608776
```

I've tried both SGD and Adam as an optimizer with learning rate = 0.01 (I have also tried 0.001 and no change) and I've tried both the `nn.NLLLoss` and `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` but they remained still during training.
Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: did you mean `nn.Softmax(dim=1)` instead of `F.softmax(dim=1)` for the last layer? because it shouldn't work using the latter functional form.

Comment: yes, I meant `nn.Softmax(dim=1)`

Comment: I changed it, but just now I realised my `optimz.step() = None` does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: did you pass the model's parameters to the optimizer?

Comment: yes, but there's something wrong with my `loss.backward` it gives me this error: `Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.`